# How to check NSDictionary for key using Objective-C literals

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

When **parsing JSON, I get NSDictionary** and go through it one (known) key at a time. When debugging a bug, I started wondering: how should I handle **missing key vs value which is zero?**

Earlier I would have used something like this to check if key exists or not:

```
    if ([dict objectForKey:@"public"])
        newItem.isPublic = [dict objectForKey:@"public"] ? YES : NO;
```

but now I wrote this using Objective-C object literals. Just started wondering, what does this check actually do:

```
    if (dict[@"public"])
        newItem.isPublic = dict[@"public"] ? @YES : @NO;
```

Should I check against nil or [NSNull null] or is there some easier, obvious, way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The new literal syntax makes no difference here. The `dict[@"public"]` code is translated into `[dict objectForKeyedSubscript:@"public"]`, which is documented to be the same as `valueForKey:`, which in turn calls `objectForKey:`.

As for the conditional test, writing `if ([dict objectForKey:@"foo"])` is the same as `if ([dict objectForKey:@"foo"] != nil)`. In other words, `[NSNull null]` counts as true here, so you have to check explicitly if you want a different behaviour. Zero can’t be directly stored in a dictionary, it would have to be wrapped in an `NSNumber`, again being treated as a true value.

See also the [Objective-C Literals spec](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html) and [NSDictionary Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html).